# How do I calculate the sum for most populus counties?

Tags: python, pandas

Only looking at the two most populous counties for each state, what are the two most populous states (in order of highest population to lowest population)?

```
State          County          Population
Dhaka          Dhaka city      120000
               Narayanganj     50000
               Gazipur         40000
Rangpur        Gaibandha       36000
               Rangpur city    54000
               Lalmonirhat     68000
Rajshahi       Rajshahi city   98500
               Bogura          56000
               Naogaon         16000
```

Comment: is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes, this is a pandas dataframe

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This function should return a list of string values.

Comment: Is `State` an index of the dataframe?

Comment: This looks like an assignment in a programming class. Maybe you will learn the most by figuring it out yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use `nlargest`

```
df.groupby(['State'])['Population'].nlargest(2).groupby(level=0).sum()

State
Dhaka       170000
Rajshahi    154500
Rangpur     122000
Name: Population, dtype: int64
```